# Copy EXCEL cell x number of times

Tags: excel, cells

I have a column of about 1000 IP addresses that I need to print 5 times in a single column.

For example

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.3
10.10.10.4
```

should become

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
```

etc, etc

Can this be done in Excel? What functions should I research?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your example is in range A1:A4, you can use this in column B as from cell B1:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1)
```

This will repeat each one 5 times.

Comment: After entering in the forumla I have to drag it to other cells in the column ..... how to make the other columns populate automatically?

Comment: @Glowie You'd have to turn to coding if you want to do something like autopopulating other cells with a formula in one cell... (unless it's google spreadsheets). If you're willing to learn excel-VBA and macros, that's your bet, though I'm not the best person to teach you that.

Comment: Ok, I'll research excel-VBA and macros