# Excel list turned into 5 rows at a time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm needing to turn this list in excel into a list that changes to the next row every 5 rows. Any help would be very much appreciated!

So I'm trying to turn

```
VS1M001WT1
VS1M090RD1
VS1M116BN1
VS1M116NP1
```

into

```
VS1M001WT1
VS1M001WT1
VS1M001WT1
VS1M001WT1
VS1M001WT1
VS1M090RD1
VS1M090RD1
VS1M090RD1
VS1M090RD1
VS1M090RD1
VS1M116BN1
VS1M116BN1
VS1M116BN1
VS1M116BN1
VS1M116BN1
VS1M116NP1
VS1M116NP1
VS1M116NP1
VS1M116NP1
VS1M116NP1
```

Comment: In other words, you have a list of unique values, and you want to "duplicate" that list where each value gets listed 5 times?

Comment: @BruceWayne essentially, yes!

Comment: I would vote to close as a duplicate, you can find your solution [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619453/copy-excel-cell-x-number-of-times). Put this in column B, or wherever you want your new list: `=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1)`. (Assuming your list is in column A).

Comment: @BruceWayne Sick! That seems to do it. Thanks for helping with that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy EXCEL cell x number of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619453/copy-excel-cell-x-number-of-times)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this macro. Suppose your list is in column A and you want the desired result in column B.

```
Sub aa()
rowCnt = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
Range("a1").Select

For j = 0 To rowCnt
ActiveCell.Offset(j, 0).Activate
Selection.Copy
Range("b1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(5 * j, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.Copy

For i = 1 To 4
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.Copy
Next i
Range("a1").Select
Next j
End Sub
```